# Convert IP address in sockaddr to uint32_t

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming

I am tyring to convert IP address (v4) stored in `struct sockaddr` to `uint32_t`.

```
//struct sockaddr in_addr;
struct sockaddr_in* addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&in_addr;

uint32_t clientIpAddr = static_cast<uint32_t>(addr->sin_addr.s_addr);
uint16_t clientPortNumber = addr->sin_port;
```

First, I am wondering if this would work at all.

Second, is it better to convert the IP address to `char[4]` and convert that to `uint32_t` later?

Third, will IP address `0.0.0.1` be converted to number 1? or something else because of byte-order?

Comment: You should not be declaring variables as `sockaddr` to begin with. Declare them as `sockaddr_in` (IPv4), `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6), or sockaddr_storage` (IP-agnostic) instead, and then type-cast them to `sockaddr*` when passing them to various socket functions (`connect()`, `accept()`, etc).  In any case, to extract an IPv4 address from `in_addr`, make sure that `in_addr.sa_family` is AF_INET`, then a type-cast to `sockaddr_in` is fine (you don't need to `static_cast` the `s_addr` value, but you should use `reinterpret_cast` on the `in_addr` cast if you are going to use C++ casts at all).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will work, yes.

According to [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), `struct in_addr` is defined as follows:

```
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t s_addr; /* address in network byte order */
};
```

so yes, you can assign it to a uint32_t (and you don't even need to cast it).

The "in network byte order" bit indeed also tells us that if you're running this on a machine that isn't big endian, you'll end up with garbage. You want to pass it through `ntohl()` to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

This conversion will work okay, as long as you will not try to print  clientIpAddr, and just re-use it in calls to `sendto` or `bind`.

To convert the address properly, you need to use `ntohl` function, which will convert from network to host byte order, otherwise your 0.0.0.1 address will have value 0x1000000 in clientIpAddr:

```
uint32_t clientIpAddr = ntohl(addr->sin_addr.s_addr);
```

Comment: nitpick: will only look like that on little endian machines. On big endian, network order and host order is the same. There also *used* to be "middle" endian machines, which were... weird :-)

Comment: You typically wouldn't need to convert the IP address from network byte order to host byte order, as socket APIs operate on IPv4 addresses in network byte order. If you want a human representation of the IP address, use `inet_ntoa()` or `inet_ntop()` or equivalent for that. You will more often want to work with the port number in host byte order instead: `uint16_t clientPortNumber = ntohs(addr->sin_port);`